# how do i make my c program randomly select

Tags: c, random

I want to make a `C` program which randomly selects 6 numbers from numbers the range `1 - 37`, without repeating any previously permutations. For example, suppose the program randomly selects `1,2,3,4,5,6`. If the next permutation is randomly selected as `2,1,3,4,5,6`, then that is OK. However, if `1,2,3,4,5,6` is selected again, that this is not OK. I want this to continue until there are no more possible sets available. How would I go about writing this `C` program?

Comment: i have not tried much as hard as i reseach i cannot find a method but if you do know could you explain in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the KNUTH shuffle answer posted below is quite elegant.  But it doesn't meet a particular requirement set forth by the OP in his question.

The OP said he wanted to be able to select all sets in random order until his program has consumed them all.  So here goes.  For purposes of demonstrate, we'll understand "select" to mean "print".

The total number of possible sets of "6 unique digits in the range of 1-37" can be expressed as:

```
TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS = 37*36*35*34*33*32 = 1673844480
```

1673844480 (1.6 billion) fits nicely within a signed 32-bit number.  And every unique set could potentially be assigned a unique integer id.

So... if you can generate a random number between [0,1673844479], we can map that to a very specific set of 6 unique integers.

To construct the set, we'll need a helper function that will allow us to keep track of which values between 1-37 have already been used during the iteration process of constructing the set.  Then a little modulo arithmetic math to help us map an ID number to it's set of 6-digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h
#include <stdint.h>

const uint32_t TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS = 37*36*35*34*33*32; // = 1673844480

// returns the Nth value value from the ordered set {1,range},
//  skipping over elements previous selected
int GetAvailableElementFromSet(int n, int range, int inuse[])
{
    int i = 0, x;
    for (x = 0; x < range; x++)
    {
        if (inuse[x] == 0)
        {
           if (i == n)
           {
               inuse[x] = 1;
               return x + 1; // +1 since the loop variable has a zero-based index
           }
           i++;
        }
    }
    return -1; // error
}


void GetSpecificSet(uint32_t setindex, int output[])
{
    int index;
    int inuse[37] = {}; // boolean array of elements already picked for the output set. zero-init to all false
    int j,k;

    if (setindex >= TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS)
        return; // error!

    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        index = setindex % (37-j);
        output[j] = GetAvailableElementFromSet(index, 37, inuse);
        setindex = setindex / (37-j) ;
    }
}
```

And just to prove that this works, we can have another function iterate over all sets:

```
void PrintSet(uint32_t setindex)
{
    int output[6];
    GetSpecificSet(setindex, output);
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", output[0], output[1], output[2], output[3], output[4], output[5]);
}

void PrintAllSetsInOrder()
{
    uint32_t index;
    for (index = 0; index < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS; index++)
    {
        PrintSet(index);
    }
}
```

Now the program above will print out all the sets starting from:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6}  // first set
{2,1,3,4,5,6}  // second set
{3,1,2,4,5,6}  // third set
```

And ending with

```
{36, 37, 35, 34, 33, 32} // next to last set
{37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32} // last set
```

And then obviously to print a random set:

```
void PrintRandomSet()
{
    PrintSet(rand() % TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS);
}
```

But the OP wanted all sets printed in random order without repeats.  This gets tricky, because we have to keep track of random number values previously generated. I can think of several ways to do this.  The most obivous candidate solution is to keep a bitmask comprised of TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS bits.  That is:

```
#define IS_BIT_SET(bmask, bitindex) (bmask[bitindex/8] &  (0x01<<(bitindex%8)))
#define    SET_BIT(bmask, bitindex) {bmask[bitindex/8] |= (0x01<<(bitindex%8));}
uint8_t* bitmask = calloc(TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS/8 + 1);
```

That's about 200MB of memory allocated.  Large, but workable.  Then we keep picking random numbers from the range [0-TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS), checking the bitmask if it's already been used, then call PrintSet with the random number after setting its bitmask position.  Repeat until all TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS have been printed.

Pseudo code for a working, yet problematic solution

```
for (x = 0; x < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS; x++)
{
    index = rand()%TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS;
    while (IS_BIT_SET(bitmask, index))
    {
        index = (index + 1) % TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_SETS;
    }
    SET_BIT(bitmask, index);
    PrintSet(index);
}
```

Now this should work just fine.  But it's going to get dog-slow as the bitmask array starts to get filled up.  The later iterations will spend most of its time just scanning the array of bits looking for an unset index value.  There have been other discussions on StackOverflow on how to do efficient and uniform permutations of large sets.  Perhaps a database is warranted.  Go search for those solutions and apply it here for the win.

Comment: thanks really helpful but right before i tick as my answer i just recetly started c but from my reading this does not look like c.

Comment: you seem to be very nollagable in c would you mind explaining to me how the program randomly selects the six digits

Comment: just tried the program did not work alright compile the program and post a link and open it and extract the source code.

Comment: @user1135474 - StackOverflow is not your personal "Mechanical Turk". Nor does it exist for others to do your homework for you. I've done a fairly good job building a solution for you with some reasonable explanations behind the algorithm. If you are too lazy to convert the above code snippits into a working program and resolve the errors yourself, then you shouldn't be a programmer.  The above code only requires knowledge of the following "C" concepts: {functions, arrays, modulo arithmetic, printf(), and rand(), and bit operators }....

Comment: @user1135474 - ... if you don't understand these basic concepts, then get a book on C, and spend the rest of the weekend learning how to get some basic programs working that uses these concepts. Then come back to stepping through the above code. I've made a quick fix to the code above in case you didn't know you had to #include <stdint.h>.

Comment: @user1135474 - And finally, the best way to learn how to use someone else's code is to compile it, run it, and preferably use a debugger to step through it.  Good luck.

Comment: ok this wasn't homework though, I just wanted to expirement with a random function. But truly i am sorry if it seemed that i was taking advantage of your help its just that i'm a beginner , i don't now how to put snippits together and i still don't understand much as i'm still 14 , I always wante to be a programmer since i was 5, but actually i do have a book let us c by Yashwant Kanetkar. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Knuth Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Gives you O(n) asymptotic complexity.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int rrand(int m)
{
  return (int)((double)m * ( rand() / (RAND_MAX+1.0) ));
}

#define BYTE(X) ((unsigned char *)(X)) 
void shuffle(void *obj, size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
  void *temp = malloc(size);
  size_t n = nmemb;
  while ( n > 1 ) {
    size_t k = rrand(n--);
    memcpy(temp, BYTE(obj) + n*size, size);
    memcpy(BYTE(obj) + n*size, BYTE(obj) + k*size, size);
    memcpy(BYTE(obj) + k*size, temp, size);
  }
  free(temp);
}
```

Ref: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#C

Comment: i like that you replied quickly but i want to actually understand how this works so could you yourself explain.

Comment: I recommend you read the linked `wiki` article. That explains things better than I could. Pay attention especially to the psuedo-code samples and the "Examples" section.